# Data warehouse: Can I tell any details from Source System on delays or blocks?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, data-warehouse

I have a MS SQL Server 2012 machine that is acting as our data warehouse currently.  We are having issues with long running jobs, and am curious if there is a way to get detailed historical logging on reasons that a job is being held up/running long?

I know this is kind of a vague question and I apologize.

Thanks, Drew

Comment: Are you talking about long running ETL jobs?

Comment: Yes, and I need detailed logging on how where they are getting stuck, or stuck on the source system.

Comment: Disclaimer: I know very little about Microsoft SQL Server. Having said that, can't DMVs be used to check on long running queries? I Googled "sql server use dmv for long running queries" and quite a few pages came up (don't know how useful they'll be to you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I am going to assume that we are talking about ETL operations for loading data into your data warehouse. One great option that you have available to you since you are using SQL Server 2012 is [creating a SSIS Catalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471509(v=sql.110).aspx) and migrate your ETL jobs to be hosted there. This offers you tons of reporting and performance counters that you can use to track and troubleshoot various ETL issues.

After you identify a baseline it really is performance tuning on your long running ETL's, SQL Server Data Tools shows performance statistics and you can manually run them to see where it it taking the most of your time. Start with the query to the source system and make sure it is tuned properly, then check your lookups and inserts and updates. There are many ways to increase performance of your ETL's. Basically ask for the minimum amount to get done what you need done, make sure you are doing set based operations for your updates as opposed to row based.

There is much more performance tuning tips depending on what you find by digging into your ETL's.